# Automated conversion of QuantumCircuit in the Mathematica package QuantumFramework into Qiskit-code

Tags: qiskit

Is it possible to automatically transform a quantum circuit, created in Wolfram's Mathematica (through the QuantumFramework package) into a qiskit code? What I thought of would be a package function that turns the circuit created through the function QuantumCircuitOperator into a python code that creates the corresponding circuit in qiskit.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Python code generation for Qiskit circuits yet. The best you can do is to make Qiskit's QuantumCircuit in the ExternalEvaluate session and use it as you would use it in any Python environment, save it, serialize it, convert it to QASM, etc.

Here I've written a small overview of the current Qiskit integration in the QuantumFramework: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/nikm/Published/QiskitConversion.nb

Comment: Yes. OpenQASM is the most extended language for interoperability among frameworks